# error LNK1181 in cmake project with static/shared libs

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

We are trying to port our cmake project [3DTK](http://slam6d.sourceforge.net/) to Windows but are running into multiple LNK1181 errors. Here is the specific error message of one of them. A full error log can be retrieved from the [appveyor CI](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/josch/3dtk/branch/master).

```
"C:\slam6d\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\slam6d\src\scanserver\scanserver.vcxproj" (default target) (115) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\obj\scanclient.lib' [C:\slam6d\src\scanserver\scanserver.vcxproj]
```

Here are the relevant parts from the `CMakeLists.txt`. The full version is available in our svn [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/slam6d/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/scanserver/CMakeLists.txt).

```
[...]

add_library(scanclient_objects OBJECT ${CLIENT_SRCS})

# compile with -fPIC so that the result can be made into a shared library
set_property(TARGET scanclient_objects PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1)

add_library(scanclient_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scanclient_objects>)
add_library(scanclient_shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scanclient_objects>)

set_target_properties(scanclient_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME scanclient CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)
set_target_properties(scanclient_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME scanclient CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)

set(CLIENT_LIBS ${Boost_LIBRARIES} pointfilter)

[...]

target_link_libraries(scanclient_static ${CLIENT_LIBS} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(scanclient_shared ${CLIENT_LIBS} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})

[...]

add_executable(scanserver ${SERVER_SRCS})

set(SERVER_LIBS ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} scanclient_shared scanio_shared)

[...]

target_link_libraries(scanserver ${SERVER_LIBS})
```

There are several puzzeling things here:

1. Why is the build of `scanserver` looking for `scanclient.lib`? It was instructed to link against the dynamic library and not the static library
2. When looking at the the full build log, the static library it builds seems to be `scanclient32.lib`. What is the additional `32` doing in the filename and even if its auto-generated, why is the linker looking for `scanclient.lib`?

The build succeeds on Linux and MacOS, so this problem is certainly MSVC specific. So why does linking fail and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Tsyvarev I tried removing the static scanclient library (See [this changeset](https://sourceforge.net/p/slam6d/code/1674/)) but the error persisted (see the corresponding [appveyor log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/josch/3dtk/build/1.0.49) at the very bottom).

Comment: Linker looks for `.lib` which describes the dynamic (`.dll`) library, not for the static library. Probably, your STATIC and SHARED libraries conflict for files generated by them. Try to comment out `scanclient_static` library creation (and using), and see how the linking process behaves.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried doing exactly that but it didn't improve the situation. See my edit at the bottom of my question for details.

Comment: The linker looks for the `.lib` file under `obj/` subdirectory... But where the `.lib` file is **actually created**? Whether the file is ever created? (You need to **explicitely export** some symbols in the header file for the `.lib` file will be created).

Comment: @Tsyvarev a `.lib` is created as `obj/scanclient32.lib`. A file called `scanclient.lib` can be found nowhere and also the build log does not mention that file except for in these error messages. How shall I interpret your comment regarding the explicit exports?

Comment: Unlike to Unix and MacOS, *by default* MSVC does't export any symbol(function) when create a shared library. And, if no symbols are exported from the library, the `.lib` file isn't created for it. This case would explain your problem well: the linker need `.lib` file for link with a library, but the file is not created for empty export list. For export symbols you should either have `__declspec(dllexport)` attributes in your header file, or set [CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) variable in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Okay, this might've been it. Adding that changed *a lot*! Now I get a very different set of errors but nothing about libraries not being found anymore. It is still puzzeling because our code used to work a year ago and we never added `__declspec(dllexport)` to anything and also `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` was news to us. I will come back here once I know that this was really the fix but it seems promising! Want to formulate it as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it?

Comment: When the problem is resolved, finding the duplicate is not so hard :) Actually, I initially was misguided by *STATIC* / *SHARED* libraries combination in your code.

Comment: I think you are correct with this being a duplicate. Thanks for identifying this! Yes, I also first thought that this was the culprit but it was only a very red herring. :)